# What is the proper procedure for removing a UIPageViewController from one of its child view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` subclass with a bunch of `UIViewController` subclasses contained inside.

At some point in one of the `UIViewController` subclasses if the user does something I want to remove the whole `UIPageViewController` system to reveal just the underlying subview it was initially added to.

I add the `UIPageViewController` subclass as a child view controller of my main view controller as follows:

```
ImageGalleryPageViewController *galleryPageViewController = [[ImageGalleryPageViewController alloc] initWithImagesAndCaptions:imagesAndCaptions];
[self addChildViewController:galleryPageViewController];
[self.view addSubview:galleryPageViewController.view];
[galleryPageViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I'm curious what the best practices for removing it from the inner `UIViewControllers` is.

What my first reaction to do is this:

```
[self.imageGallery removeFromParentViewController];
[self.imageGallery.view removeFromSuperview];
```

(Where in my `UIViewController` subclass I have a reference to the `UIPageViewController` subclass it's contained in, and I tell the `UIPageViewController` subclass to be removed.

Is this... okay? I'm afraid it feels sloppy as if I remove the `UIPageViewController` that contains the `UIViewController` making the call, maybe the second `removeFromSuperview` call won't end up being called as the view would be removed.

Would it be better to have a specialized method on the `UIPageViewController` subclass that performs both of the above methods? Something different all together?

Furthermore, why is it necessary to call both? Why does `removeFromParentViewController` not remove its `view` as well? Why is it necessary to even *add* both?

Answer (score 0):

I would comment but I don't have enough rep. :(

I'd suggest what you said:

> Would it be better to have a specialized method on the UIPageViewController subclass that performs both of the above methods?

You'd easily be able to that using an NSNotification.